# How to backup preinstalled Mac OS Lion to DVD

Tags: macos, osx-lion, backup

Bought a Mac Pro with Mac OS X Lion preinstalled on the HD.

I want to backup this OS to DVD. Is it possible?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not customer support](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128579). This is a programming question and answer site, not [Apple support](http://www.apple.com/support)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create a full image of your hard disk, using [`CloneZilla`](http://clonezilla.org/) and to save it to an external hard drive. Whenever you wish to install it again on your Mac, you simply restore the image.

CloneZilla will only save the space you have in use. So if you have a 500 GB disk and only 10 GB is in use, it will cost you about 10 GB of disk space (even less since it's compressed!).

Answer (score 0):

The common OSX tools for thsi include [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) and [Superduper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/superduper/superduperdescription.html)

They both will take a full copy and make it bootable as well as allowing incremental backups to carry on for ongoing backups.